# github action combine workflow_dispatch and push in the same workflow

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to figure out how to combine manual trigger and other trigers (push for example) in the same workflow

This is my manual action

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: environment
        default: DEV
        required: true

env:
  ENVIRONMENT: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}
.
.
.
```

I want something like

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    - dev
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: environment
        default: DEV
        required: true

env:
  ENVIRONMENT: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }} or {{ DEV if dev }} or {{ PROD if main }}
.
.
.
```

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this using an expression in the ENV field. You would have to evaluate and set the env variable according to the branch name in a job step, then add it to the GITHUB_ENV or share it with outputs.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to do it:

```
name: Print environment variable

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - development
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: string
        default: DEV
        required: true

jobs:    
  prod:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref_name == 'master' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'PROD' }}
    env:
      environment: PROD
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print value
        run: echo ${{ env.environment }}
        
  dev:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref_name == 'development' || github.event.inputs.environment == 'DEV' }}
    env:
      environment: DEV
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print value
        run: echo ${{ env.environment }}
```

Of course, if you have the same steps for both environments and do not wish to repeat them then consider using [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#creating-a-reusable-workflow).

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify why I used type `string` for environment. Yes, I've noticed that you used `environment` as type for input, but the docs are not quite clear on that part. [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callinputsinput_idtype) it says that inputs can only be of type `boolean`, `number` or `string`, yet [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputs) in the example it shows not only `environment` type, but also `choice` type.

Comment: notice that my environment type is environment and not string

Comment: Should this also work with a free github account or do we need a plan for that?

Answer (score 5):

according [to docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable), you can setup an env variable with:

```
echo "{environment_variable_name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

so in your case something like this should work (did not test):

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Set env
    run: |-
      echo "ENVIRONMENT=$(
      if ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}; then
        echo ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}
      elif [ ${{ github.ref_name }} == dev]; then
        echo DEV
      elif [ ${{ github.ref_name }} == main]; then
        echo PROD
      fi
      )" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Test env
    run: echo "woo!!" ${{ env.ENVIRONMENT }}
```